# Not able to write surevyId in csv file using beanshell postprocessor in jmeter. Null is being written instead of surveyId

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
{
"code": 200,
"surveyId": 3239640,
"success": 1
}
```

I want to write surveyId in csv file but null is being written instead of surveyId. I have written beanshell script as follows:

```
vars.put ("Response Data",ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString());

log.info(vars.get("Response Data"));

try{

String surveyId = vars.get("surveyId");

}

catch(Exception ex) { log.warn("Error in my script", ex); throw ex; } log.info("surveyId is " +surveyId); f = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//garim//Downloads//apache-jmeter-5.1.1//apache-jmeter-5.1.1//bin//SurveyId.csv", true); p = new PrintStream(f); this.interpreter.setOut(p); print(surveyId); f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `surveyId` variable is not defined anywhere in your script therefore it's null, you need to get it using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and the JSON Extractor needs to be **before** the Beanshell PostProcessor
2. In general [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting and given [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) you can amend your code to look like:

   ```
   String surveyId = (new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).surveyId) as String
   new File("C://Users//garim//Downloads//apache-jmeter-5.1.1//apache-jmeter-5.1.1//bin//SurveyId.csv") << surveyId << System.getProperty("line.separator")
   ```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)